# is there a way to show splash screen until the webview fragment finish loading?

Tags: android, kotlin, splash-screen

I have a MainActivity that `installSplashScreen()` at first, then it will load the `WebView`, the webviewFragment is in other file, I am trying to use `splashScreen.setKeepOnScreenCondition{ }` to keep splash screen showing until the webviewFragment reach to `onPageFinished()` state, how am I supposed to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several alternatives to communicate both components:

1. you may use a listener in your fragment that notifies the activity,
2. you may cast the activity from fragment context to notify it,
3. you may use the activity ViewModel and observer pattern to notify the change
4. singletons though not recommended
5. event bus implementations
6. send a broadcast and receive it with a BroadCastListener in your splash or MainActivity.

Comment: is there a way to talk to the webViewClient? I just noticed that it is the onPageFinished() inside webviewClient.

Comment: Yes you can create a WebView Interface (I believe it 's called WebViewClient) between javascript and Android to communicate both ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cl_container_splash"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

- Frame Layout (Parent)

  - WebView (visibility = gone)
  - Splash Screen (visible)

Now load your url, and in your `onPageFinished()` call following.

```
binding.webView.visibility = View.Visible
binding.root.removeView(binding.clContainerSplash)
```